# Git: ignoring files after deleting .gitignore file

Tags: git

I had a magento setup in which I created a .gitignore file which is like as follows:

```
########   MAGENTO RELATED FILES AND FOLDERS    ######
var/*
media/*
app/etc/local.xml
minified/css/*
minified/css_secure/*
minified/js/*
minified/media/*
```

later I figured out that due to this rule `var` and `media` dirs also got ignored and were not part of commit.
So I tried to comment `var/*` and `media/*` lines, I tried to delete, the `.gitignore` file, committed and pushed to remote repo. but nothing works.

Any chance to get them back under tracking? Please note there is only one `.gitignore` file.

Many thanks!!

Comment: Git track files, not dirs. So, that's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git tracks content; directories are not content, they are structure. What you can do is, drop empty placeholder files in `var/` and `media/` and track those. That will bring the directory structure under git's supervision.

You can keep the `var/*` and `media/*` lines in your .gitignore, just add an exception for the placeholder files like

```
!var/README.md
!media/README.md
```

Comment: .gitkeep is a common placeholder filename for this purpose

Comment: Also, as an option is to create `.gitignore` with "*" as a content.

Comment: @josefAssad you were right and so were `Kan`. Placeholder works for me. Its absolutely different than SVN.

Comment: git != svn is the answer to about 25% of the git questions here in stackoverflow. :) Glad you solved your problem.